# load content inside of the container

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

i'm try to setup ajax content box that when you click on the icon show up the container box pushing the content.

well, everything is fine, the problem is that the content is not loading inside the container but outside of it on the body, according to the jquery docs the append make this function, so everyone know why is not loading the page on the container?

```
$(function(){
    $('.user-link a') .click(function(e){
        var a = $(this),
            href = a.attr('href'),
            content = a.appendTo('#buser-box');

        content.load(href + '#buser-box');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#buser-box').show('fast');
    });
})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have an element with id=buser-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `content` variable.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.user-link a') .click(function(e){
        var a = $(this),
            href = a.attr('href'),
            box = $('#buser-box'),
            content = a.appendTo(box); // This may not be necessary

        // Loading into the div, not the appended to element, might not be what you want.
        box.load(href + '#buser-box');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#buser-box').show('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to load inside of `#buser-box`, simply do:

```
$('#buser-box').load(href + '#buser-box');
```